# The best place to store logic in React app?

Tags: reactjs

I have two components. e.g. Dashboard and Card

**Dashboard**:

```
render() {
        const elements = this.props.cards.map((card, key) => {
            return (
                <Card item={card} onSave={this.onCardSave}>
            )
        })
    }
```

**Card**

```
render() {
    return (
        <div class="card">
            <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.item.checked} onChange={this.onChangeChecked} />
            { this.someCondition() && <input type="text" value={this.state.item.name} onChange={this.onChangeName} />}
        </div>
    )
}
```

So text field visibility is depending on some condition. For example:

```
function someCondition () {
    return this.state.item.checked
}
```

!! This logic is only for Card instance

So where is the best place to store this logic?

Inside *Card*? (like my code)

Inside *Dashboard*? (pass all events in props for example)

If you can provide me some article on this theme, I would be very grateful

Comment: [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/where-do-i-belong-a-guide-to-saving-react-component-data-in-state-store-static-and-this-c49b335e2a00#.786y1o4n7) should be good starting point

Answer (score 3):

A normal approach community is working with, is separate components in two types:

1. *presentional components*: Are concerned with how things **look**.
2. *container components*: Are concerned with how things **work**.

But one of the important things to notice is: "While container components tend to be stateful and presentational components tend to be stateless, this is not a hard rule. Presentational components can be stateful, and containers can be stateless too."

Like in your case, your logic's example depends only with internal logic of the component, so in my opinion, it would be better to keep inside the Card component.

Usefull articles: 
Dan Abramov, the Redux's creator:
https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.kyc0tpd11

Answer (score 1):

You can read up on stateless vs stateful components (or smart vs dumb). This SO link is quite clear [ReactJS difference between stateful and stateless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34512696/reactjs-difference-between-stateful-and-stateless)

In your example, Dashboard would hold the state for the card as im guessing you need to know whether a card is checked so you can do something else (like toggle the display of other components) l. If you had this logic in card you then need to try and reference that in the dashboard which becomes annoying and more difficult.

Hope that helps