# Get string result from function React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I have created a component that connects to redux and returns the currently loaded `item's` name as the navigation title.

But when I try to get the title from this component it breaks with this error:

```
Error: `title` cannot be defined as a function in navigation options for `StockScreen` screen. 

Try replacing the following:
{
    title: ({ state }) => state...
}

with:
({ navigation }) => ({
    title: navigation.state...
})
```

This is my component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

let Title = () => {
    if(this.props.item === null || this.props.item === undefined, this.props.item === {}) {
        return '';
    }else{
        return this.props.item.TradeName;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    item: state.stockItem.item,
});

export default ConnectedTitle = connect(mapStateToProps)(Title);
```

And this is how I have attempted to implement it within my react-navigation stack:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: Tabs,
            navigationOptions: {
                header: null,
            },
        },
        StockModal: {
            screen: StockModal,
            navigationOptions: {
                header: null,
            },
        },
        StockScreen: {
            screen: StockScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                headerRight: (<ConnectedSaveButton/>),
                title: ConnectedTitle,
            },
        },
    },
    {}
);
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve here. But you should use ConnectedTitle() for running that function. try   title: ConnectedTitle(),

Comment: I tried but i get 'cannot call a class a function'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a React Component to the title in navigation options, while it should be a string. I think you need to use the headerTitle to achieve what you want

```
StockScreen: {
    screen: StockScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        headerRight: (<ConnectedSaveButton/>),
        headerTitle: (<ConnectedTitle />),
    },
}
```

From the documentation

> **title**
>
> String that can be used as a fallback for headerTitle. Additionally, will be used as a fallback for tabBarLabel (if nested in
>   a TabNavigator) or drawerLabel (if nested in a DrawerNavigator).
>
> **headerTitle**
>
> String, React Element or React Component used by the header. Defaults to scene title. When a component is used, it receives
>   allowFontScaling, style and children props. The title string is passed
>   in children.

Comment: Hey thanks so much, I actually did realize it needed a string I was just trying to generate a string with some logic and redux; however as you pointed out you cant really make that work but I used headerTitle and it works brilliantly. I thought headerTitle was a thing but my auto-complete for it was failing so I assumed it didnt exist, shows me for not reading the documentation correctly! (PS, I should have known considering thats how I used headerRight lmao)

Comment: Sometimes when using all these layers in your app like  redux / react-navigation it's hard to understand where the problem actually is... I'm happy I was able to help :)

Comment: Indeed, first time using react, react-native and redux so when I get stuck it feels overwhelming where to find the problem! But redux is amazing and im glad im learning all of it